# Show custom profile information on manage page MVC5

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to add custom data to the MVC5 authentication with this tutorial.
http://blog.falafel.com/customize-mvc-5-application-users-using-asp-net-identity-2-0/
This works fine.
Now i want to show the custom field i have added to the manage profile page. 
Here you can only change the password now.
This is my controller where i try to get the user information:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
            : "";

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //Here starts my error
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            HasPassword = HasPassword(),
            Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
            BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

By var manager = new UserManager......
I get the error
The type of namespace 'UserStore' could not be found.
But this is a standard namespace MVC uses for there authentication.

Am i missing something here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works for me if I bring in the follow namespace:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Can you see if that resolves your problem?

Comment: Yes that work's! but now that function always returns null. no User id. I can find a lot of people have trouble with this. But can't figure out why.

Comment: Does User.Identity.GetUserId() return a userId? Are they logged in?